# Asynchronous validation

Tags: jquery, validation, asynchronous

I'm using: http://www.jquery-steps.com/ in my project. A good Jquery plugin for adding wizards.

I want to make a server validation, if an email is present on the server. And if its not valid the wizard have to stay on the same step. If it is valid, the wizard should move to the next step and get the info related to the email.

I tried this on

```
        onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) {

            event.preventDefault();
            var action = ...
            ...

            if (currentIndex == 1) {
                var form = null;
                if (action === "import") {
                    form = $("#link-account-form")
                }
                else if (action === "create") {
                    form = $("#create-profile-form");
                }


                form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
                var formValid = form.valid();
                if (formValid && newIndex == 2) {
                    if (action === "import") {
                        var login = form.find(".temp-login").val();

                        // here I want to get async validation to work...
                        return $app.getUserByLogin(login, function (userAccount, status, xhr) {
                             if (userAccount != null) {
                                $("#thirdStep .temp-name").val(userAccount.user.name);
                                $("#thirdStep .temp-gender").val(userAccount.user.gender);
                                var birthday = UI.Formatter.parseDatetime(userAccount.user.birthday);
                                $("#thirdStep .temp-birthdate").data('datetimepicker').setLocalDate(birthday);
                                $("#thirdStep .temp-telephone").val(userAccount.user.phone);
                                $("#thirdStep .temp-cellphone").val(userAccount.user.cellPhone);
                                $("#thirdStep .temp-address").val(userAccount.user.address);
                                $("#thirdStep .temp-neighborhood").val(userAccount.user.neighborhood);
                                $("#thirdStep .temp-zipcode").val(userAccount.user.zipCode);
                                $("#thirdStep .temp-city").val(userAccount.user.city);
                                $("#thirdStep .temp-state").val(userAccount.user.state);
                                $("#thirdStep .temp-id").val(userAccount.user.id);
                                $("#thirdStep .temp-picture-url").val(userAccount.user.pictureUrl);
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                UI.Notify.error("", $("#res").data("retrieve-error"));
                                return false;
                            }
                        }).fail(function (data, status, xhr) {
                            UI.Notify.error("", $("#res").data("retrieve-error"));
                            return false;
                        });
                    }
                    else if (action === "create") {
                        ...
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return formValid;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Do you have already faced this situation? how did you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the question using async: false on the ajax request inside $app.getUserByLogin. Thanks for your attention.